# Can I use PCA to create new songs?

Tags: pca

So lets create a vector space where the magnitude is the pitch of a note and each note in a song is a new orthogonal vector. Would I be able use principal component analysis to describe enough of the data to

1. generalize types of music?
2. create new songs by making them out of the principal vectors?

Comment: This seems more like a research question that should be answered by experimenting.

Comment: The main difficulty might be to create new *good* songs.

Comment: Some additional difficult will be in defining what constitutes a song and what constitutes new.